# this.instantSearchInstance.__forceRender is not a function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, algolia, nuxt.js

This is my main code:

```
<template>
  <div class="blog" id="blog">
    <div class="blog-container" >
      <ais-instant-search
        :search-client="searchClient"
        index-name="index_name"
      >
        <MainHeader />
        <ais-state-results>
          <template slot-scope="{ query }">
            <ais-hits :escapeHTML="false" v-if="query && query.length > 0">
              <template slot-scope="{ items }">
                <SearchResult :items="items" />
              </template>
            </ais-hits>

            <div class="interface">
              <main role="main">
                <nuxt />
              </main>
            </div>
          </template>
        </ais-state-results>
      </ais-instant-search>

      <MainFooter></MainFooter>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I wanted to integrate algolia-instantsearch with my nuxt app. The task i was trying to implement was if there is no query length then render the child contents and if there is any query show the search results.

But to access the query i need to include `ais-state-results` which is making the code go nasty.

1) If i add `<no-ssr>` of nuxt and it is working fine.
2) If i remove the `ais-state-results` it works find

Expected results:
-> should render normal page when no query is entered
-> if any query is provided by the user, then show the search results page

Actual results:
-> error: this.instantSearchInstance.__forceRender is not a function
-> tries to load page around 2 mins and crashes the page